# When moving something to a point with vector math the enemy gets there and then disappears

Tags: c++, sdl

I have been trying to use vectors to move objects at angles and I did get it working, however, when I try to move an object to a specific point it gets there and then disappears. In my code I test if within the next step if it will reach it's destination and if it will, I snap it to the destination.

```
void Dot::moveToVector(Vector& vec)
{
    float dx;
    float dy;

    dx = vec.X - position.X;
    dy = vec.Y - position.Y;

    Vector distanceVec(dx, dy);

    float distance = distanceVec.Length();

    float scale;

    scale = speed / distance;

    velocity.X = dx * scale;
    velocity.Y = dy * scale;

    if(velocity.X < scale || velocity.Y < scale)
    {
        velocity.X = 0;
        velocity.Y = 0;

        position.X = vec.X;
        position.Y = vec.Y;
    }

    move();
}
```

When I debugged it, one frame after it snaps into position, the x and y values of the position = -nan(0x400000).

Comment: I'm not familiar with sdl, but it looks like velocity and speed aren't actually declared anywhere in your method. Are those declared elsewhere?

Comment: My bad guys, I realized that it doesn't become NULL. I just added it.

Comment: Yes velocity and speed are declared within the dot object. I guess I need to add information about it that isn't presented within my code next time. I will remember!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scale = speed / distance;
```

If `distance == 0` what do you think will happen?

Comment: Thank you very much. I added a test for distance and set it to speed if it was equal to zero. I'm learning what not to do every day!

Answer (score 2):

When your object reaches the target position, distance becomes zero. Then you are dividing by distance. I suspect that is why your object disappears!

Here is a more straightforward way to set it up:

```
void Dot::moveToVector(Vector& vec)
{
    Vector distanceVec = vec - position;
    float distance = distanceVec.Length();

    if(distance <= speed)
    {
        velocity.X = 0;
        velocity.Y = 0;

        position.X = vec.X;
        position.Y = vec.Y;
    }
    else
    {
        Vector direction = (distanceVec / distance);
        velocity = direction * speed;        
    }

    move();
}
```